# TextView setTexSize property not working as expected in an adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, textview

following are the lines of code of my WordAdapter

```
 public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int colorResourceId) {
    super(context, 0, words);
    mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    final Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    TextView textView = (TextView) 
    listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    textView.setText((currentWord.getTextId()));

    if (Fragment1.isActive == true){
        textView.setTextSize(55);

    } else if (Fragment1.isActive == false){
        textView.setTextSize(35);

    if (Fragment2.isActive == true) {
        textView.setTextSize(35);
      }else if (Fragment2.isActive == false){
        textView.setTextSize(35);

    if (Fragment3.isActive == true) {
        textView.setTextSize(35);
      }else if (Fragment3.isActive == false){
        textView.setTextSize(35);

    return listItemView;
}
```

but the problem is all the fragments in my project gets updated with the **textSize of 55**...

i also noticed one peculiar thing that of the three fragments i have in my project.. if i click on the `Fragment1` first then all the fragments updates the **textSize to 55**.. but if i click other two Fragments first.. `textSize` remains **unchanged to 35**...

All i want is to setTextSize to 55 if Fragment1 is active onscreen and the textSize should be 35 if other two Fragments are active..

i read in other questions that if i use the context parameter of my `WordAdapter` class its possible.. like to use `context.getClass().getSimpleName()` but am unsure of how to do it... please guide me...

Comment: Write `else` part for each if too . And do not call ` notifyDataSetChanged();` inside `getView()` . Also you are setting hardcoded pixel value instead of this ise dimen SP size .

Comment: added `else` part for each IF... and also removed to notifyDataSetChanged(); inside the getView() .. but no change.. still the same problem presists...  also edited my question code as you suggested @ADM

Comment: solved it.. used Context to know which Activity is running... also posted an answer for others .. it might help somebody...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the WordAdapter declare a Context

```
private Context mContext;
```

in WordAdapter ArrayList ..

```
mContext = context;
```

then .. check which activity is running and set the TextSize accordingly by the following code:

```
if (mContext.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Activity1") || mContext.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Activity3")) {
    onClickTextView.setTextSize(55);
} else {
    onClickTextView.setTextSize(35);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use booleans directly in `if` statements - you do not need to do `== true` or `== false`. Also if a boolean is not true, then it is false, so you do not need to explicitly check if it is true, then check if it is false. That being said, your code does not need to be that complicated.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textView.setText(currentWord.getTextId());

if (Fragment1.isActive) {
    textView.setTextSize(55);
} else if (Fragment2.isActive || Fragment3.isActive) {
    textView.setTextSize(35);
}
```

Also, you should be using dimension resources for text sizes rather than hardcoded values, but that's a different issue altogether.

Comment: Tried this.. but once inside Fragment1 text size changes to 55 in other two fragments too.. it's like the app is not executing the else if  block itself..

Comment: Are you changing `Fragment1.isActive` back to false when you switch fragments?

Comment: I have Fragment1.isActive = true; in my onStart() method and Fragment1.isActive = false; in my onStop() method....

Comment: the reason why I checked explicitly true and false is that in the last else part of my code is else { textView.setTextSize(55);}  the text size remains 55 and it never changes back to 35 even if it's inside Fragment 2 or 3 where the IF is coded to be 35..